# How can i convert stl into json from github python program

Tags: python, json, converters

I am working on my college project: I need **stl** file converter into **g-code** using **python** program. For that, i have used this program file from **github** link - https://github.com/VanHulleOne/SciSlice ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9YRA.jpg)). The program is running fine, but I have one problem, that I am unable to convert **stl file into json**; I have asked this issue to **scislice**  programmer:

> I want to know whether scislice converts stl file into gcode or It coverts JSON file into gcode? We want to convert STL to gcode so that Our 3D printer takes commands and is able to print. If your program coverts JSON file into gcode so I want to know How would I convert my stl file into a JSON file??"

[Main program gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIWs8.jpg)

[Error during uploading stl file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SZfL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned gui by you doesn't serve the purpose of converting `stl` to `json`
1.[assimp2json](https://github.com/acgessler/assimp2json):Convert files in `40+` 3D file formats, including Collada, 3DS, OBJ, LWO, FBX, Blender, X, STL, PLY, MS3D, B3D, MD3, MDL, DXF and IFC to plain json.

2.[numpy-stl 2.15.1](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-stl/) :`pip install numpy-stl`

3.[Online convertor](http://www.tmpvar.com/tmp/stl-json.html): Drag and Drop